# ember.js: conditional positioning of nested resource outlet

Tags: ember.js

starting from the [bloggr-client](https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client) of the [ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/) i would like to include the outlet of 'post' inside the 'posts' each loop, resulting in some kind of accordeon-like behaviour.

e.g., the router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});
```

the template (cleared of html tags for legibility) should do something like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  {{#each model}}
    {{#link-to 'post' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
    {{#if :post_id given and corresponding with this post}}   <-- that's pseudo code ;-)
      {{outlet}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

any idea how to accomplish this properly?

UPDATE 1:

to clarify, output on url '/posts' should be:

```
post 1 title
post 2 title
post 3 title
```

on url '/posts/1':

```
post 1 title
complete post 1
post 2 title
post 3 title
```

on url '/posts/2':

```
post 1 title
post 2 title
complete post 2
post 3 title
```

Comment: You probably have this solved already, but I recently found a really nice [accordion component](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-widgets/accordion) that would help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to be able to displays all of the posts on the `posts` route as an accordion? You're going about it wrong because you can only have one `{{outlet}}` per template. What you want to do is build a [component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/), which would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars id="components/post-card">
    {{#link-to 'post' post tagName="h2"}}{{post.title}}{{/link-to}}
    <p>{{post.snippet}}</p>
</script>
```

And call it in the `posts` route like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  <ul>
  {{#each}} -> if you're iterating through the model, no need to specify
    <li>
    <h3 {{action makeActive}}>{{title}}</h3>
    {{#if active}}
        {{post-card post=this}}
    {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

You would add `active` as a property in your model, and `makeActive` would be an action in your controller that would make `active` true for the given model, and make the other ones false. This would model an accordion, though your route would not update.

Comment: no, i don't want to show all of the posts, only the one selected by 'post/:post_id' if inside route 'post'. updated question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure if/how you can have conditional outlets. You could accomplish almost the same thing with components, except that the route wouldn't update, but it'd still have the accordion functionality.

Comment: For Ember 2.0, plain #each is changing.. see https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email